# angular 2 pipe getting maximum and minimum value

Tags: javascript, angular

I try to display maximum and minimum values in my table how can we get with angular 2 built in pipes here i try like this

```
 <td > {{value.max | MaxMinPipe}} </td>

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'MaxMinPipe'
})
export class MaxMinPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value) {
   return Math.max(value);
  }

}
```

Comment: What table? [mcve]

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to use the same pipe for both min/max? What is value.max?

Comment: I need to use two pipes for max and min  like this may be `<tr *ngFor="let rpi of rpitable">
    <td > {{rpi.north_h | MaxPipe}} </td>    <tr *ngFor="let rpi of rpitable">
    <td > {{rpi.north_h | MinPipe}} </td>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I can see two ways to achieve this:

**1st.** - Create a pipe that returns both (max and min value) - IMO, it's the preferable approach:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'maxMin'
})
export class MaxMinPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any[], prop: string) {
    if (!Array.isArray(value) || value.length === 0 || !prop) { 
      return value;
    }

    // Here we sort the items based on passed `property`
    value.sort((a, b) => b[prop] - a[prop]);
    const max = value[0][prop];
    const min = value[value.length - 1][prop];

    return [max, min];
  }
}
```

Instead of `sort` you can also use something like this (not sure which one has a better performance):

```
const mappedArr = value.map(x => x[prop]);
const max = Math.max(...mappedArr);
const min = Math.min(...mappedArr);
```

**Template**:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Max value</th>
    <th>Min value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngIf="data | maxMin: 'myProperty' as result">
    <td>{{ result[0] }}</td>
    <td>{{ result[1] }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that using the `as` syntax as I did above, in addition to improve the performance, because it just calls the pipe **one** time, it provides more readability :)

[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/gVdfzeboPK3cqUscvR9n?p=info)

**2nd.** - Split into 2 pipes, like this:

**MaxPipe**:

```
...
export class MaxPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any[], prop: string) {
    if (!Array.isArray(value) || value.length === 0 || !prop) { 
      return value;
    }

    value.sort((a, b) => b[prop] - a[prop]);
    return value[0][prop];
  }
}
```

**MinPipe**:

```
...
export class MinPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any[], prop: string) {
    if (!Array.isArray(value) || value.length === 0 || !prop) { 
      return value;
    }

    value.sort((a, b) => a[prop] - b[prop]);
    return value[0][prop];
  }
}
```

In **template**:

```
<td>{{ data | max: 'yourProperty' }}</td>
<td>{{ data | min: 'yourProperty' }}</td>
```

[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/NpKPTtVOmOeqOqWIljCN?p=info)

Note that you must pass the property you want to use to compare and then get the min and max value. Probably, in your case it's "north_h".

**Tips:**

- Don't forget to add the `Pipe` to the declarations in your `NgModule`.

Answer (score 3):

Its pretty easy way to get max amd min using [ngx-pipes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-pipes#max)

```
 <td > {{rpi.north_h | max}} </td>
 <td > {{rpi.north_h | min}} </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { PipeTransform, Pipe} from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({
        name: 'MaxValueFilter'
    })

    export class MaxPipe implements PipeTransform {
           transform(value:any[]) : number {
                let maxValue : number = value[0].north_h;
                for(var  val in value){
                  if(maxValue < val.north_h){
                     maxValue = val.north_h;
                  }
                }
                return maxValue;
           }
    }
```